# Kivy app with black screen using kv language

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

**Hello! i'm nubie in python and i tried build a kivy app but it return a black screen as show in img below**

[image]

I try find the solution but i can't find anyway...

Follow below the code:

Main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyGrid(Widget):
   name = ObjectProperty(None)
   email = ObjectProperty(None)

   def btn(self):
      print("Name:", self.name.text, "email:", self.email.text)
      self.name.text = ""
      self.email.text = ""




class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
<MyGrid>:

    name: name
    email: email

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Email: "

            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline:False

            Button:
                text:"Submit"
                on_press: root.btn()
```

**In the VS code does not return any error or warning**

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your `kv` file should be named `my.kv`.

Comment: Simple mistake and that gave me a headache!

Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using "Builder" to call a specific .kv file, then the .kv file has to be called the same thing as you have in the class where you build the app.

In your case,this class is called MyApp.

Due to the way Kivy works, you can't have "app" in the name, and as such, you're .kv file needs to be called "my.kv".

Comment: Simple mistake and that gave me a headache!

Thank you for the explanation.